# Facebook page plugin within android webview

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, facebook

I have no experience with making an app so i decided to just make a website and run that in an app. The website works fine in a browser and also in the app except:

My only problem is that the website uses a page plugin (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) that's used on my standard site (this is because I'm using php includes so i don't have to make each page twice) but inside the app it just will not display. 
I've looked everywhere I could think of for the solution (as well as reading about 6 different threads on this site).

My app's code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView xWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        xWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        xWebView.loadUrl("THE SITE URL");
        xWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = xWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    }
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(xWebView.canGoBack()) {
            xWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

If I don't get any help I'll just have a php if statement change the content for that page and use a link to Facebook instead but the plugin would be preferable.